# special method for an object to override tuple expansion?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, overloading

I will provide an example of the problem in question, in case the title was not clear enough.

Let's say that I have a `class Point(object)` that represent 2d coordinates.
Is it possible to create a "magic" method that will allow the following?

```
x, y = point
```

Maybe some hacks with iterators?

Comment: Might it be easier to just do something like `x, y = point.coordinates()`?

Comment: @lambo477 : my question is very specific, your comment is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide an `__iter__` method.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

p = Point(1, 2)
x, y = p
assert (1, 2) == (x, y)
```

Be careful though. This means your class suddenly becomes safe to use in many other places where it might have previously thrown a type error.

eg.

```
def add_1(x):
    return x + 1
l = list(map(add_1, p)) # works, because the point is iterable
```

Ergo, you may want to provide a method other than `__iter__` that provides the iterator.

eg.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def coords(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

p = Point(1, 2)
x, y = p.coords()
assert (1, 2) == (x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks! I really like this usage of `yield`

Answer (score 4):

you can simply tap into the iterator protocol of the object and accomplish this

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.points = (x,y)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.points)

p = Point(1,5)
x,y = p
print x,y
# 1,5
```

take a look at http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#sequence on more information on how a custom object can be converted into an iterable; or more precisely how one would use an object like an iterable.

Comment: `return iter((self.x,self.y))` would be better than `return iter(self.points)` as it doesn't require the object to store the `x` and `y` values twice.

Comment: sure @DanD. the implementation is under the assumption that obj.points might come in handy as well; like the `coords` function implemented in @Dunes' answer.

Comment: If it does, `points` should be implemented as a property. In which case the two would be equivalent.