# Overriding tuple() behaviour on object

Tags: python

I can use `__iter__` to define how a custom object looks as a `dict`. Is there any way to separately customize the `tuple` conversion? (Yes, I do realize that this is potentially confusing, and probably <s>rarely</s> almost never a good idea.)

Default behaviour:

```
>>>o = MyClass()
>>>dict(o)
{'value': 1, 'attr_1': "foo", 'attr_2': "bar"}
>>>tuple(o)
(('value', 1), ('attr_1', "foo"), ('attr_2', "bar"))
```

Desired behaviour:

```
>>>o = MyClass()
>>>dict(o)
{'value': 1, 'attr_1': "foo", 'attr_2': "bar"}
>>>tuple(o)
(1, {'attr_1': "foo", 'attr_2': "bar"})
```

Here's a minimal example of the class `o` belongs to:

```
class MyClass(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.value = 1
       self.attributes = {'attr_1': "foo", 'attr_2': "bar"}

   def __iter__(self):
        yield ("value", self.value)
        for k, v in self.attributes.items():
            yield (k, v)
```

Related, but not about having different structs for dict and tuple: [special method for an object to override tuple expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057851/special-method-for-an-object-to-override-tuple-expansion)

Comment: I doubt you can do this. Why not define a method `o.to_tuple()`?

Comment: What's the type of `o` ?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Yes, that's in fact what I'm doing, but I was curious if I could also make `tuple(o)` behave the same, as a kind of syntactic sugar

Comment: @stamaimer It's belongs to a custom class (new-style), if that matters?

Comment: Can you show the code of custom `__iter__`?

Comment: @stamaimer The exact layout of the class is irrelevant to this question, I think. But I can add a minimal example to the question!

Comment: Why don't you custom the `__repr__` method of your custom class?

Comment: @stamaimer `__repr__` has nothing to do with the object conversion to tuple type.

Comment: @stamaimer I guess I was unclear, but it's the behaviour of `tuple(o)` I want to change. I don't think `o.__repr__` is involved in any way there

Comment: You are change the representation of built-in tuple. Subclass the built-in tuple and custom the `__repr__` of it.

Comment: What should happen if one of the attribute names is "value"? Then the conversion to dictionary is broken.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yep, while not currently possible, that's indeed a bug waiting to happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a much better idea to write your own constructor for a tuple:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):

    @classmethod
    def from_default_tuple(cls): # your alternative constructor
        pass
```

And if you really want to change `tuple`, there is nothing wrong with this line: (except your IDE will think you are a bit crazy)

```
tuple = MyTuple.from_default_tuple
```

But it's definitely a bad idea. I'd recommend you to use `MyTuple.from_default_tuple()` instead

Comment: It needn't to custom the constructor of tuple. Because the custom class is iterable. The difference between built-in tuple and custom tuple is the way to represent the object.

Comment: @pythad Thanks! Overwriting `tuple` is not a place I'm going, but good for reference.

Comment: @leo I would actually go a step further: don't rely on `__iter__` to produce a stream of values suitable for *either* `tuple` or `dict`, and supply explicit `to_tuple` and `to_dict` class methods. (To be sure, `to_dict` as an *implementation* detail can still simply be a wrapper around `dict(self)`, because your `__iter__` implementation is legitimate. Just don't expect it to be an all-purpose conversion routine to arbitrary types.)

Answer (score -1):

You can custom the special method `__str__` or `__repr__` of tuple.

```
class my_tuple(tuple):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(%r, %r)" % (self[0][1], dict(self[1:]))

test = MyClass()
print my_tuple(test)
```

UPFATE

You can rewrite `__iter__` of your custom class to achieve your purpose.

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield self.value
    yield self.attributes

o = MyClass()
tuple(o)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting? `o` in the example is not a tuple. And `tuple._repr__` is not called when doing type conversion...

Comment: Because you implement `__iter__` in the `MyClass`, You can construct a tuple from a instance of `MyClass`. When you call `tuple(o)`, the interpreter call the `__repr__` of tuple for inspect. As i commented in another answer and your question. What you want is change the representation of the built-in tuple.

Comment: And i don't know why you want to construct a tuple from the instance of your custom class.

Comment: You have still only changed the representation of the my_tuple. If you try e.g. `t=my_tuple(test);print t[0]` you will see the difference.

Comment: I guess this is the relevant code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6969eaf4682beb01bc95eeb14f5ce6c01312e297/Objects/clinic/tupleobject.c.h

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am well aware of that possibility, but then again that changes the behavior of `dict(o)`, etc...